# Yarn local-dirs - per node setup

Tags: hadoop-yarn, devops, hdp

I've had a series of devops issues from time to time on our production cluster. Every now and then, `/` partition gets overwhelmed on couple of nodes. Long story short, it turns out that these nodes had 1 instead of 2 data drives. This would not be an issue if we don't have a following setup on our cluster:

```
   <property>       
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>       
      <value>/data1/hadoop/yarn/local,/data2/hadoop/yarn/local</value> 
   </property>
```

Some devops or whoever, noticing there are no /data2 partitions on the *smaller* nodes, came up with the idea to simply go with `/` partition. Since `/` is 16GB, some of the more data-demanding jobs quickly fill the thing.

Now, my question: does yarn support per-node setup of yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs?

I resolved the problem by removing `/data2/hadoop/yarn/local` from the story, but it doesn't feel perfect.

We're using HDP 2.6.4.

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YARN allows this since each Node Manager would read it's local yarn-site.xml.  However, I don't know how you would do this in Ambari.

Comment: Good enough, I will try it out and see what will happen.